# Passing a message via CLI to git but still open $EDITOR

Tags: git

Is there a way to pass a commit message to git via cli (ala `git commit -m "Message here"`) but still open the message in `$EDITOR`? The goal is for a script / shell function to open the commit message editor with a dynamic message depending on certain factors which can be determined in the shell, but still give the user the opportunity to edit the commit message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `-e` in addition to your `-m` to instruct git to start the editor.

```
git commit -m "My awesome message" -e
```

Source: [`git commit documentation`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit)